# Make pointer from an unknown type

Tags: interface, go

Is it possible to make an equivalent code to the following without mentioning a specific type (SomeStruct in this case)?

```
// takes SomeStruct{} and returns &SomeStruct{}
func MakePointerFromStruct(someStruct interface{}) interface{} {
    obj := someStruct.(SomeStruct)
    return interface{}(&obj)
}
```

I've created a [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/kvTYwnhBOT)

---

My actual problem is that I need to cast to &User{} some data from a session (which I get from redis and which is in a form User{}) but code which operates on that deserialized value doesn't know anything about its type and tries to cast it to an interface..

The problem is that there is one pointer method on User{} which modifies data. And to cast to an interface value in an interface{} variable must already be a pointer: &User{}

Some code to make it clear:

```
type User struct {}
func (u *User) FillFromOauth(name string) {
  u.Name = name
  //...
}

type UserInterface interface {
  FillFromOauth(name string)
}

func someFuncWhereCastingOccurs(userObj interface{}) {
  user := userObj.(UserInterface) // 
}

data := User{}
someFuncWhereCastingOccurs(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import "reflect"

func MakePointerFromStruct(someStruct interface{}) interface{} {
    ptrValue := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(someStruct))
    reflect.Indirect(ptrValue).Set(reflect.ValueOf(someStruct))
    return ptrValue.Interface()
}
```

Comment: I need pointer to point to original value so struct's pointer methods could change it. In your example I see new struct is allocated and a value of old one is copied to it..

Comment: @user3668351: But Go is pass-by-value. The fact you are passing the struct means you cannot affect the original. This is the same as what you are doing with the code sample you showed for "equivalent code to the following". You are also "allocating a new struct" by declaring a variable of struct type (`obj`); and then you are copying the struct value to it (which is already a copy of the passed value, since Go is pass-by-value; you are copying it again).

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem on just taking address of your User{} variable?

```
data := &User{}
someFuncWhereCastingOccurs(data)
```

Take a look at this example: http://play.golang.org/p/xYqfr5G4mw

PS. By the way, it's not casting, it's [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Answer (score 0):

A pointer can be converted to the type-unsafe generic pointer by

```
return unsafe.Pointer(&p)
```

That value can then be cast to whatever pointer type you choose.

Comment: No way to simplify that code?

    userObjPtr := unsafe.Pointer(&userObj)
    structType := reflect.TypeOf(userObj)
    return reflect.NewAt(structType, userObjPtr).Interface().(UserInterface)

Comment: @user3668351 If the function should return the pointer already cast to the new type, it would be something like `return (*UserInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&userObj))`

Comment: Hmm.. I get invalid memory address when I use `*(*UserInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&userObj))`.. Look here please: [http://play.golang.org/p/7KhMHpf-hH](http://play.golang.org/p/7KhMHpf-hH)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I don't understand why you can't use the WhenTypeIsKnown code though?